# Sequelize findAll is returning a array with a null object instead of an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mariadb, sequelize.js

```
const getAmbassadors = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const ambassadors = await Ambassador.findAll({ 
            
            include: [{model:Ticket,attributes:[]],
            attributes:{include:[[sequelize.fn("COUNT",sequelize.col("tickets.id")),"ticket_count",]]},
         });
        return res.status(200).send(dataResponse('success', { ambassadors }));
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

When there are no ambassador objects in the database i get  the following output:

```
"ambassadors": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "name": null,
                "referral_code": null,
                "email": null,
                "institute": null,
                "ticket_count": 0
            }
        ]
```

i was expecting an empty array to be returned, but an array with a single object with null fields is being returned.
the problem gets fixed when this line is removed:

```
attributes:{include:[[sequelize.fn("COUNT",sequelize.col("tickets.id")),"ticket_count",]]},
```

but i need the ticket count. can someone point out how this can be fixed?

Comment: Could you add the generated SQL in the post?